# How to make condtiion if string not equal to null and greater than equal to 10 and less than equal to 1000?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain edit text in which user enter amount and i have to make condition if amount not equal to null and must be greater than equal to 10 and less that equals to 1000. But i am getting error.

code:-

```
if (!hasFocus) {
            if (m_szAmount.length()==0 && Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount) < 10 && Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount) > 1000) {
                m_InputPointsLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
                m_InputPointsLayout.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.enter_points_error));
            } else {
                m_InputPointsLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
                m_InputPointsLayout.setError(null);
            }
        }
```

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statement. Your question says you want to check condition 1 and 2 and 3 but you have done is **OR(||)**

```
if ((m_szAmount.length()!=0 && Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount)>=10 && Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount)<=1000) && (m_operatorSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() > 0 && m_circleSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() > 0)) {
        m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: I am now want to make opposite of wriiteen condition

Comment: What do you mean by opposite

Comment: if (m_szAmount.length()==0 && Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount) < 10 && Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount) > 1000) {
                    m_InputPointsLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    m_InputPointsLayout.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.enter_points_error));
                } else {
                    m_InputPointsLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    m_InputPointsLayout.setError(null);
                }

Comment: This is on Focus listener

Answer (score 0):

> NumberFormatException is an Exception that might be thrown when you
>   try to convert a String into a number, where that number might be an
>   int .

At first check  **`isEmpty()`** and Use **[&&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)** Operator instead of **`||`** .

Rectify Your **`if`** **STATEMENT** .

```
m_szAmount = m_InputPoints.getText().toString().trim();
if(!m_szAmount.isEmpty())
{

  if (RewardUtil.isConnected(mContext)) 
    {
        if (Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount)>=10 && Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount)<=1000) && (m_operatorSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() > 0 && m_circleSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() > 0)) {
            m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        try {
            CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.no_internet_connection_warning));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);

    }
}

else
{

  Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this,"String is Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the function added below. 
First of all you have to check weather the string is null or not. 
if it is not null then check it is empty or not.
If it is not empty then check the value in it is integer or not.

```
private int checkIntegerValue(String strComparedValue)
{
    int xAmount = 0;
    if(strComparedValue != null && !strComparedValue.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            xAmount = Integer.parseInt(strComparedValue);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Your exception if string contains non integer value
        }
    }

    return xAmount;
}
```

Your Code

```
if (!hasFocus) {
        if (checkIntegerValue(m_szAmount) < 10 && checkIntegerValue(m_szAmount) > 1000) {
            m_InputPointsLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
            m_InputPointsLayout.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.enter_points_error));
        } else {
            m_InputPointsLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            m_InputPointsLayout.setError(null);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

check m_szAmount contains only number or not, if m_szAmount contains any string then it will throw exception of number format.

m_szAmount = m_InputPoints.getText().toString().trim();

```
 if (RewardUtil.isConnected(mContext)) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(m_szAmount)) {

                        if (m_szAmount.matches("[0-9]+")) {

                            int amount = Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount);

                            if (amount >= 10 && amount <= 1000) {

                                m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(true);

                            } else {

                                m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(true);


                            }

                        } else {

                            Log.d("format_issue", "number_format_issue");

                        }

                    }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.no_internet_connection_warning));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);

                    }
```